# Reload of mdadm.conf live server

Tags: raid, mdadm

Is there a way how to make system to use updated mdadm.conf without reboot? I added spare group, but its not used yet - when there is a disk missing, spare is not automatically attached. I was told that this config is loaded on boot from initram, but i cant afford to restart live server. Still would be useful to have automated hot-sparing.

Comment: The commandline [mdadm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) tools can be used to make the desired modifications to running MD devices

Comment: Edit your question to show what the current state is, e.g. `cat /proc/mdstat`, `cat /etc/mdadm.conf`